# Problem running composer install in a Laravel Project on Google Compute Engine (Debian 9)

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, debian, google-compute-engine

I am running into a basic problem that I really can't get over with.

I have created a new VM Instance on Google Compute Engine to run my Laravel development WebApp. After pulling the development from my GitHub I fail to run the composer install command...

Here is the error message displayed after running "composer install" inside the project:

[image: After running "composer install"]

Debian version : 9 (codename Stretch)
Apache 2 version : 2.4.25
PHP version : 7.3.12
Composer version : 1.2.2

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: try **composer self-update**

Comment: I have the following error when I try to run that command : [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException]
  Command "self" is not defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like your composer was installed using debian package manager. Run `which composer` and add it to your question detail.

It's recommended that you uninstall your composer and install it using the following commands;

```sh
cd ~
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer -o composer-setup.php
sudo php composer-setup.php --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

Then run `composer install` if it's a development environment or `composer install --no-dev` if it's a production machine.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved ! I found out that my composer version was too old. I had to re-install composer. Now it is perfectly working. Thanks for your help !